# Azure devops : Continuous deployment for sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have the database table, stored procedures script, once the script file has pushed to  TFS, the changes have to be deployed on the database
using azure devops.

How to setup SQL  script file for build pipeline and release pipeline in Azure devops

thanks in advance,

Comment: Your question is far too broad to get a complete answer here, but you want to start working with Database Projects to facilitate continuous deployment.

Comment: Hi dave , 
my question it's not too broad, I have to run the SQL script, using azure devops , SQL Server Database Deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Where you stuck exactly?
Add 'Azure SQL Database Deployment' task from market place to run sql script.
Choose 'Deploy type' accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

@rAj is correct, when you add a new "Azure SQL Database Deployment' task to your agent Job, you can select to run an inline SQL script:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## For Build pipeline

1. Add the `SQL Server database deploy` task
2. In `Deploy SQL Using`, choose `Sql Query file`.
3. In `Sql File`, you can specify the location of your `Sql file`.

[image]

## For Release pipeline

The process is similar to build pipeline.

[image]

Comment: This only allows for 1 script to run.